# Quickbooks SDK Could not start quickbooks when quickbooks closed

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I have a .net Console application and another one that is a Win Forms application. Using SDK 13.0, and QuickBooks 15.0 Enterprise.
Both work fine when QuickBooks is open. I granted access to both of these apps. Both granted access for when QB is closed to run as the Admin user. When QB is closed, both apps give the same error. "Could Not Start QuickBooks" I have read a lot of threads. I have triple checked my QBW file path. I have unchecked "Keep QuickBooks Running for quick startup". I have tried running as Administrator vs not.

Both work fine when QB is open, and they even work immediately after I close QB, but about a minute later they stop working. Perhaps the QB session is slow to close after you close the application.

`sessionManager.OpenConnection2("MBI", "MBI QB CRM ConsoleIntegration2", ENConnectionType.ctUnknown);`

`connectionOpen = true;`

`sessionManager.BeginSession(qbpath, ENOpenMode.omDontCare);`

`sessionBegun = true;`

I am at a loss right now. The application needs to work when QB is closed, as I think the SDK allows this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Most issues are around the QBW path. I have written this to my log and copied it to file explorer and it opens the file, so I believe it is correct.

Thank You
Ian

Comment: See https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/1143302-troubleshooting-could-not-start-quickbooks for other suggestions on not being able to start.

Comment: Does the file path you're passing to your program EXACTLY match the file path shown within QuickBooks when you hit the F2 key on your keyboard?